# c# remove xml node including child ones if another match found

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml file with lots of placemark tags having few nodes in it. I want to remove the whole placemark tag if any duplicate found. If this possible with linq? Actually I am not much familiar with Linq so can you please guide me in right direction.

```
                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
          <Document>
            <Placemark>
              <name>Entity references example</name>
              <description>
                    &lt;h1&gt;Entity references are hard to type!&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;&lt;font color="green"&gt;Text is 
                  &lt;i&gt;more readable&lt;/i&gt; 
                  and &lt;b&gt;easier to write&lt;/b&gt; 
                  when you can avoid using entity references.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
              </description>
              <Point>
                <coordinates>102.594411,14.998518</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
              <name>Entity references example</name>
              <description>
                    &lt;h1&gt;Entity references are hard to type!&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;&lt;font color="green"&gt;Text is 
                  &lt;i&gt;more readable&lt;/i&gt; 
                  and &lt;b&gt;easier to write&lt;/b&gt; 
                  when you can avoid using entity references.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
              </description>
              <Point>
                <coordinates>102.594411,14.998518</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
              <name>Entity references</name>
              <description>
                    &lt;h1&gt;Entity references are hard to type!&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;&lt;font color="green"&gt;Text is 
                  &lt;i&gt;more readable&lt;/i&gt; 
                  and &lt;b&gt;easier to write&lt;/b&gt; 
                  when you can avoid using entity references.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
              </description>
              <Point>
                <coordinates>102.594411,14.998518</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>

              <Placemark>
              <name>Entity references example</name>
              <description>
                    &lt;h1&gt;Entity references are hard to type!&lt;/h1&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;&lt;font color="green"&gt;Text is 
                  &lt;i&gt;more readable&lt;/i&gt; 
                  and &lt;b&gt;easier to write&lt;/b&gt; 
                  when you can avoid using entity references.&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
              </description>
              <Point>
                <coordinates>112.594411,14.998518</coordinates>
              </Point>
            </Placemark>
          </Document>
        </kml>
```

Edit: Tried this but it is not removing the whole placemark tag

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/a.xml");
xdoc.Root.Elements("Document").GroupBy(i => (string)i.Element("Placemark")) .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)) .Remove();
```

The placemark can have other elements too like for example:

```
<Placemark>
  <name>Absolute Extruded</name>
  <description>Transparent green wall with yellow outlines</description>
  <styleUrl>#yellowLineGreenPoly</styleUrl>
  <LineString>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates> -112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,2357
      -112.2549277039738,36.08117083492122,2357
      -112.2552505069063,36.08260761307279,2357
      -112.2564540158376,36.08395660588506,2357
      -112.2580238976449,36.08511401044813,2357
      -112.2595218489022,36.08584355239394,2357
      -112.2608216347552,36.08612634548589,2357
      -112.262073428656,36.08626019085147,2357
      -112.2633204928495,36.08621519860091,2357
      -112.2644963846444,36.08627897945274,2357
      -112.2656969554589,36.08649599090644,2357 
    </coordinates>
  </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Comment: Trying this but it is not working                            var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:/a.xml");

            xdoc.Root.Elements("Document").GroupBy(i => (string)i.Element("Placemark"))
                    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                    .Remove();

Comment: Put that in the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your attempted code which compare element equality by its string representation, with addition of *default namespace* handling :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
xdoc.Root
    .Elements(ns+"Document")
    .Elements(ns+"Placemark")
    .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .Remove();
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wSlKTk)</kbd>**

> *"Why do we have to use XNamespace? Is it compulsory to use it?"*

Note that your XML has [*default namespace*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/757cbs7s(v=vs.71).aspx), declared at the root element, which URI is `"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"`. Based on the definition of default namespace, the root element along with all descendant elements without prefix are belong to this namespace, hence the use of `XNamespace`.

Comment: Thanks a lot har07! Can you suggest how can I save this to another xml file?

Comment: Why do we have to use XNamespace? Is it compulsory to use it?

Comment: @user1254053 updated the answer to briefly explain why the use of `XNamespace` here...

Comment: If I want to see how many duplicates I have found so just adding xdoc.Root
    .Elements(ns+"Document")
    .Elements(ns+"Placemark")
    .GroupBy(i => (string)i)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).Count will get me the number, right?

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the distinct Placemarks

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var query = doc.Root
                .Element(ns + "Document")
                .Elements(ns + "Placemark")
                .Select(x => new  
                {
                    Name = x.Element(ns + "name").Value,
                    Description = x.Element(ns + "description").Value,
                })
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Description })
                .Select(g => g.First());
```

Then just write them back to a file (or what ever wonderful things you want to do with them)

> **Note** : This will not work if the Placemarks aren't **EXACTLY** the
>   same

Comment: Thanks Saruman, but I am not sure what extra nodes there could be so I need to check for whole placemark and see if there is any duplicates then remove it. Can you help me in achieving this.

Comment: @user1254053 Har07 your answer